# COUNT(DISTINCT) and COUNT(*) + GROUP BY give different results

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We're querying one of data sets for unique IDs

```
SELECT count(distinct id) FROM [MyTable] LIMIT 1
```

Another query ran a similar command

```
SELECT count(*) From  ( select id FROM MyTable group by id) A ;
```

The first command is more efficient, but the output should be identical. However, they are getting different results. The first query returns more results by about 1.5% of the dataset, of over 100 million rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(DISTINCT field)` is just an estimate. If you need exact results you can use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(field)`.

This is explained in the query reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#countdistinct

Answer (score 2):

Check [COUNT([DISTINCT] field [, n])](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#countdistinct) definition

```
It is a statistical approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact.
```

The second query returns exact count, thus the difference